# PHP cant get session to store UserID after declaring it on login form

Tags: php

I am a PHP novice so please forgive my lack of knowledge.

So I have a login form that is run using the following (it all works fine)

```
    <?php include 'connectionDetails.php'; ?>


<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php 

if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])) 
{
    $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $password = $_REQUEST['password'];

    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $password = stripslashes($password);


    $sql = "SELECT UserID, Username, Password FROM Users WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?";

    $user = $username; 
    $pass = $password;
    $userid = $sql['UserID'];

    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, array(&$user, &$pass));



    if( !$stmt ) 
    {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }   

    sqlsrv_execute($stmt);

    if (sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt) > 0) 
    {
        $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
        $_SESSION["username"] = $user;
        $_SESSION["userid"] = $userid;
        header('location: index.php');
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Sorry wrong details!";
    }

}

?>
```

Once the user is logged in all is fine and I can use those session variables to display the name of the user that is logged in.

Now I am creating a separate script that will insert into the database and more specifically against the user that is logged in at the time.

This is a separate script that is run when I click submit on a button:

```
<?php

session_start();

if ( isset($_SESSION['username']) ){
 echo $_SESSION['username'] . $_SESSION['UserID'];
}

?>
```

I feel like I might possibly have declared it wrong or over-complicated it, I would appreciate any guidance.

**EDIT**:  This just echoes the letter "S" for some reason.

Comment: which database are you using? what is the output of `sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt)` ?

Comment: well i know that the variable for username works because i've called it elsewhere and it shows the username